# Can't parse localstorage angular 2

Tags: angular, local-storage

I'm trying to console.log a token I have added to localstorage. Here is the code:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('Member Info: ', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY')));
  }
```

This looks right to me, but when I run it I get the following error.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Anyone see anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because your data is already an Object and has no need to be parsed again.

Simply try with this:

```
console.log('Member Info: ', localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY'));
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Is the typical JavaScript error for when you try to parse to JSON Object an element that is already a JSON Object.

**Update:**

Seems that you have issues when saving to LocalStorage, so here goes a head's up!

```
   // To save to LocalStorage
   localStorage.setItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY', JSON.stringify({
      testData: 123
    }));

   // To read from LocalStorage
   console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY')));
```

To clean your LocalStorage:

Press F12 while in browser (for Chrome), go to Application tab, open the LocalStorage tab and select your application name. You'll find there your LocalStorage, remove it.

Comment: SrAxi, I think you were right. However, when I try to display as you suggest, I get Member Info: [object] [object] returned. As it should be a JSON object, I would think it display the key value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it displays `[object] [object]` because is already an Object, in order to see it properly you can do `JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY'))`. This happens when you use `console.log` with arguments. If you ONLY `console.log(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY'))` you will be able to see the Object.

Comment: That's the strange thing. Either way I do it it comes back as [object][object]. I tried:     console.log('Member Info: ', JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY'))); and I tried: console.log('Member Info: ', localStorage.getItem("LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY")); with the same result.

Comment: @cnak2 I have just updated my answer. In order to test it properly. Wipe your LocalStorage and try save/read again with this code. I'll add how to quickly clean your LocalStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Stringify the token before storing in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY', JSON.stringify({'aa': 'bb'}));
let token = localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY');
JSON.parse(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to transform the JSON object to a string:

```
console.log('Member Info: ', JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('LOCAL_TOKEN_KEY')));
```